# Google maps API using UK town or post code

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, google-maps, c#-4.0

I'm working on a system at the moment that will work similar to yell.com, where you can enter a location (either Town or post code) and it will return say all other towns with in say a 10 mile radius.

I've found plenty of code that will allow me to enter post code, and I'm sure it's easy to convert to allow town, so maybe have 2 text boxes would be easy enough, or one text box that checks what you've entered and can work out if it's a town or postcode, probably wouldn't be too hard either, BUT I was just wondering if anyone knows a way of doing this straight through the API so we just chuck it whatever we have and that works it out...

if not no worries just a thought :)

Cheers

daz

Comment: You could use google's [geocoder](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/)

Comment: yeah I'm currently using geocoder (which is cool :)) I have no problem getting an address from a post code or getting an address from a town, and I have no problem writing a routine that could work out from a textbox if you've entered a postcode or town, I was just really wondering if geocoder was clever enough to just take anything in and work it out... hmmm I guess I've never actually tried that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yep I can ..sorry guys I've answered my own question here :)

```
var address = 'doncaster';
//var address = 'LS2';    
geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    alert(results[0].formatted_address);
}
})
```